# bpy.data.images["ID"].save_render("XXX") changes color space

Tags: python, texture-baking, uv-image-editor, color-management

I tried to save a baked image using

```
bpy.data.images["Image Id Name"].save_render("C:/path/to/file.png")
```

but this always changes the colorspace and I couldn't find where to set the colorspace for save render in the
[documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.html?highlight=settings%20color_mode#bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.color_mode)

Finally I solved it by passing the image editor UI area, where the image is in and using `bpy.ops.image.save_as`

```
for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.data.images['bakedTexture'].filepath_raw = filenameVariations
            bpy.ops.image.save_as(override, filepath = filenameVariations)
            print ("Generated file: ", filenameVariations)
```

For the future, does anyone know how to do it with `save_render`?

Because the way I did it, I do not have control over compression and image bit depth.

I am on Blender 2.80

Comment: You would have to set the color management settings and file format settings in the scene (e.g. `bpy.context.scene.view_settings.view_transform`, `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format`, `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format.color_depth`, `bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format.compression`). I can post this as an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hey @Robert  , thanks for the answer! 
I had already tried these:
`# set ImageFormatSettings (only applying to save as render)  
settings = scene.render.image_settings  settings.file_format = "TIFF"  
settings.color_mode = "RGB"
settings.color_depth = "16"
settings.quality = 100
settings.tiff_codec = "LZW" `
but these could not repair the color distortion which is my problem. And in these settings there is no colorspace parameter that could solve the color problem, if I saw right in the API. Any other ideas? THX

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue but found that the Sequencer (Render Properties tab, Color Management) seemed to be the cause for colorspace change when using save_render. Setting it to "Raw" fixed the issue for me.

```
bpy.context.scene.sequencer_colorspace_settings.name = "Raw"
```

Comment: thx. Timn. Gonna check...

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and setting the `view_transform` to `Standard` fixed the issue for me in Blender 2.91.2.

```
bpy.context.scene.view_settings.view_transform = 'Standard'
```